# is parallelStream termination well defined?

Tags: java, java-8

I find I struggle slightly with the consistency guarantees offered by the parallel streams:

```
1. myList.parallelStream().map(mymapper).forEach(myFn)
2. // Is myFn guaranteed to be called for each element in myList here ?
```

In other words, can I be sure that all the forkJoinTasks that will execute myFn are *completed* at line 2 ?

Comment: Unless mymapper or myFn throws an exception why do you think it would not be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The parallel tasks within a complete stream pipeline are executed synchonously. Line 2 will be executed only after all the tasks have completed.

The [package documentation for java.util.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) states,

> In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning.

Note however that any *side effects* accomplished by the `forEach` tasks **might not** be visible to other threads. In practice, `forEach` can only operate by having its action perform side effects. As mentioned in the [`Stream.forEach` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), the action must use proper synchronization or other constructs in order to ensure thread-safe operation and proper visibility of side effects.